# How can I determine the initial conditions for the fit applied to the data obtained from the ellipsometry measurement?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, material-science, computational-physics, error-analysis

For thin film solar cells, I need to know the refractive and extinction coeffiecients of these materials in order to make optical calculations of some materials on the computer.

For this I had to use the ellipsometry device. But ellipsometry gives me data of psi and delta parameters or dielectric function. I need to be able to extract the n and k values ​​from the graph created by these data points.

For this, I use the application of ellipsometry called EllyReg. Fit functions are given here by default. But the main thing is determining the initial condotions. In addition, the function to be fitted varies greatly according to the received data. For example, for ZnO, the Cauchy fit and the data matched and the least square value was below 1. But I could not succeed in any kind of modeling of the PbS-i material.

I tried the Lorentz oscillator model, but because I didn't know how to determine the initial conditions, I made random trials of initial values for hours, but I couldn't get a result.

[image]

(The brown line represents the fit taken according to the initial values ​​entered.)

[image]Then I did a literature review.

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/action/downloadSupplement?doi=10.1002%2Fadfm.201908200&file=adfm201908200-sup-0001-SuppMat.pdf

In the supplementary material I shared the link of, they said that they could find the nk values ​​of the same material with the 'Gaussian-broadened Lorentz oscillators ("Voigt")' model, but they did not go into details.

At this point, I first tried to find the best fit using the curve-fitting function in python, but the initial R square value was too high for the PbS-i material. For this, I first digitized the received data. I converted this data as an array. Then I applied the curve fitting function, but the result was meaningless. (I will share the code as png. )

[image]

The reason for this may be that I could not define the Lorentz oscillator formula properly. Because there is a complex part. At that point, I was confused. That's why I used a real part of the model.

As a result, I hoped that the python curve fitting function would give the initial values ​​for the best fit. This logic worked fine in cauchy. Worked partially on Tauc-Lorentz approximation. But I could not reach a satisfactory result.

Note that the data received has an energy value between 1.5 eV and 5 eV. If I can get a nice fit that will cover at least 1.5 eV to 3.3 eV in this range, at least it will work.

Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Can you please explain: do you consider the thickness of a film as a parameter to be fitted or do you treat it as given? And one more question: in what conditions your ellipsometry measurements were conducted? It is probable that you had your film laminated on the substrate. Do you have measurements from substrate without film? If not, how do you account for it (do you treat optical constants and thickness of substrate as given)?

Comment: @goroshek sir firstly thank you for your interest.  At first I measured the thickness of the material.It is 292 nm.  And I hold it constant. Then I fitted according to some arbitrary initial conditions. However, I didn't get good fit. So, after getting some initial parameters for the fit formula I let the program to fit once again by giving thickness as parameter.    For the conditions, I did spin coating of PbS-halide on Silicon substrate. Before measuring film's values, I did calibration measurements by measuring silicon substrate and then SiO2. So yes I treated as given.

Comment: Ok, I think i know how i would try. You can use a perturbation theory to derive analytical equations for n and k. If you know data (psi1, delta1) from bare Si/SiO2 substrate and you know psi2 and delta2 for Si/SiO2/ThinFilm then the differences psi2-psi1 and delta2-delta1 govern you the equation to be solved for n and k. In your case I would not try to fit measurements (your material can be neither Drude nor Cauchy, etc.). I would just extract n and k for every wavelength. If you are interested in exact formulas you can contact me through chat and I'll try to send you needed files and pics.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139617/ellipsometry-analysis-discussion
this is the link to chat where we can discuss this further

Comment: Sir @goroshek , I am very, very excited and eager to learn what you want to teach. And I am highly grateful to you. However, I am not allowed to chat because I am new and the site says 'You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here.'

Comment: ok, I will try to type down an answer below this topic today or tomorrow's evening

Comment: Sorry, hard for me to find enough time. If you somehow will join the chat I will attach to you some files which can be helpful. Please let me know if your problem will be resolved in any way; if it will not then I will type the answer here when I find the time

Comment: Dear Sir @goroshek I am already in the chatroom. The problem has been solved.  And I am so happy to see you again. And I can't wait to learn what you recommend or say to me. I am inquisitive about your work. I was checking this page thousands of times daily to hear from you.
Best regards Sir.

Comment: Sir @goroshek I would like to offer some suggestions that I think will be useful for new users like me.
I did not understand how to use the code for my own data.
How do we download which library in python?


Frankly, if there was a sample jupyter notebook code, I think a lot of people would benefit from your code on how to call which functions from an example.

Answer (score 0):

To make fitting easy for you, you really need to understand the physics underlying the resonances and what each model does. Most ellipsometry models have highly restricted regimes of use. Many fit the tails of oscillators.

The Lorentz oscillator model is Kramers-Kronig consistent. Roughly, this means it is physical. It looks like you only used one oscillator per layer, though. The most straightforward instructions I would give a novice is to fit as many oscillators as there are bumps in the data, and possibly two oscillators that are outside the data range at low and high energy for each layer. The downside is the number of parameters makes the fit take longer, and long lists of parameters aren't pretty for publication.

You might even be lucky enough to do the following first. Using your optical data, directly calculate the optical constants as if the material was a homogenous material with a mirror surface. If you have a region of photon energies where the optical constants match closely the ideal optical constants of the top material, then you have little reflection from the first boundary and can start your fit there and add more oscillators later. This is more rigorous if you have several angles of incidence.

As for initial conditions, you can find the optical constants as a function of energy of the ideal materials somewhere online and then fit each material with Lorentz oscillators. You should know roughly the thicknesses of each layer. You then have some initial conditions.